# When not to use 'because' in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> The reason why he was rejected was **because** he was too young.

The above sentence is improved by replacing **that** in place of **because**.  My query is why *because* is not the correct form here?

Comment: Related: [Is it correct to say "The reason is because ..."?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/is-it-correct-to-say-the-reason-is-because) - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange. My personal opinion is that both are acceptable, but on the exams, stick with *that*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Because' is redundant. It lets the reader know that the next part of the sentence is the reason for the previous part, but the subject of the sentence is already identified as 'the reason', so it's unnecessary.

Including both sounds stilted, and is officially incorrect (though many people find it acceptable). [This article](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/072303ReasonBecause.htm) (which I have shamelessly appropriated from [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/is-it-correct-to-say-the-reason-is-because) to the same question) goes in greater detail.

Comment: FWIW, as a native speaker, "the reason is because" sounds **very** wrong to me. Say either "the reason is that" or "this is because".